# Snow Leopard: Keyboard shortcut to move window to a different monitor?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook

On Windows 7 there is a nice keyboard shortcut:

> Windows-shift-leftarrow

or

> Windows-shift-rightarrow

which moves the current window to a different monitor.

**Is there a keyboard shortcut like this on the MacBook Pro (Snow Leopard)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible out of the box.

You will need additional software, such as [Size Up](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/), or (untested) [MercuryMover](http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover/).

<sup>More general "hotkey" applications such as [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) and [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) might also be capable of doing this</sup>